# jquery 1.6.2 and 1.4.2 issue.. how to fix this?

Tags: jquery

I have a few jquery thinngs added to my site like gallery, callendar, autocomplete
the problem is that all works except that when I click on a image the main image is not changing. I used to click on a thumbnail and in a larger div I get the larger picture displayed, but this thing isn't working since I replaced jquery 1.4.2 with 1.6.2. What is the difference between them and how can I fix this?

here is the js code for my gallery on main page, gallery on car_show page and a little thumbnail gallery to show related products

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('#newsflash-text').cycle({
        timeout: 5000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
        fx:      'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        pause:   1,   // true to enable "pause on hover"
        cleartypeNoBg:   true, // set to true to disable extra cleartype fixing (leave false to force background color setting on slides)
        pauseOnPagerHover: 0 // true to pause when hovering over pager link
      });
      $('#slideshow').cycle({
        timeout: 5000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
        fx:      'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        pause:   1,   // true to enable "pause on hover"
        pager:'#pagerslide',
        cleartypeNoBg:   true, // set to true to disable extra cleartype fixing (leave false to force background color setting on slides)
        pauseOnPagerHover: 0 // true to pause when hovering over pager link
      });

//for scroll box
$('#scroll-box').cycle({
  timeout: 0,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
  fx:     'scrollHorz', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
  prev:   '#arrowprev', // selector for element to use as click trigger for next slide
  next:   '#arrownext', // selector for element to use as click trigger for previous slide
  cleartypeNoBg:   true, // set to true to disable extra cleartype fixing (leave false to force background color setting on slides)
  height:         150, // container height
  pauseOnPagerHover: 0 // true to pause when hovering over pager link
});

// for slideshow with thumb image
$('#img-slide-large').cycle({
  fx:     'fade',
  speed:  'slow',
  timeout: 6000,
  pager:  '#nav-thumb',
  pagerAnchorBuilder: function(idx, slide) {
    // return sel string for existing anchor
    return '#nav-thumb li:eq(' + (idx) + ') a';
  }
});
});
</script>
```

is there any way to fix this? if I remove the jquery 1.6.2 and install 1.4.2 then this little part is working but then fails the autocomplete feature. Is there any way to merge those 2 jquery files to have all elements working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!  I just tried another release of jquery and jquery 1.4.4 works fine. everything is running now. So if any of you have this issues when effect X requires 1.4.2 version and effect Y requires 1.5.2 version, just try replace your jquery release with one that's between this releases.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get the latest version of cycle plugin? http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/download.html

Comment: I tried it just now, no good.. the thing is that the cycle ftom this script is working, but when I press the thumbnail it's not changin the big picture.. I have 5 picures in a row of a product and they are cycling but if I want to choose another one to show it big it's not working. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I get Error: $("#usual2 ul").idTabs is not a function
Source File: http://188.237.135.33:3000/cars/26

Comment: and where this come from? for sure it's java but how get this working? how come with jquery 1.4.2 works fine. Can you help me wth this?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$("#usual2 ul").idTabs("tabs2");
</script>

I have this at the bottom of the page..

Comment: If you remove that line does it fix the problem?